# Canvas drawImage scales my square image to a rectangle

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have a fairly simple test, a 400 x 400 white image with text on it saying "1" over and over again.

I draw it on a fairly simple 1000 x 1000 canvas, trying to resize it to 100 x 100.

```
var image = new Image();
document.body.appendChild(image);

image.addEventListener("load",function (event) {
    var image1 = event.target;
    var tempCanvas = window.document.createElement("canvas");

    tempCanvas.style.width = "1000px";
    tempCanvas.style.height = "1000px";
    tempCanvas.style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";

    document.body.appendChild(tempCanvas);

    tempCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image1, 0, 0, 100, 100);
});

image.src = "1.png";
```

But despite all that being squares, I end up with an odd-looking, deformed, weirdly scaled result that's rectangular, low quality, and without having any of its dimensions being 100px.

[image: Odd result]

On the left, you can see the original image, on the right, that's the top left corner of my canvas.

If you want the original image, here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDkLx.png

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `width` and `height` values on the canvas element prior to the `drawImage()`, rather than relying on the styles as you are.

Setting the `width` and `height` attributes corresponds to setting the dimensions of that canvas element.

Once you've defined the dimensions of a canvas element, the rendering behavior of the canvas becomes much more predicatable:

```js
var image = new Image();
document.body.appendChild(image);

image.addEventListener("load",function (event) {
    var image1 = event.target;
    var tempCanvas = window.document.createElement("canvas");

    //tempCanvas.style.width = "400px";
    //tempCanvas.style.height = "400px";
    tempCanvas.style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";

    tempCanvas.width = 100;
    tempCanvas.height = 100;

    document.body.appendChild(tempCanvas);

    tempCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image1, 0, 0, 100, 100);
});

image.src = "https://puu.sh/C4HE2/d96b531d08.png";
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

img {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

The code snippet above shows the original source image with red border, and the down-scaled canvas rendered image with blue border - hope this helps!

Comment: If I do that, the image is still weirdly resized, only thing is the canvas is smaller. Also, that doesn't suit my needs, I won't always have an image that's exactly the size of the canvas. https://puu.sh/C4Hz2/b81c6f836d.png

Comment: strange - can you please upload your source image, eg the image with the 1's

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDkLx.png Done :)

Comment: @YannBergonzat thanks :-) , just updated answer with code snippet - seems to work for me, does this produce expected results for you?

Comment: Okay so the answer, which I found thanks to your updated snippet, is that I shouldn't set the width and the height of my canvas through the style attribute, but through the width and height attributes directly or else it just screws every operation because I guess they rely on these values and not on the CSS ones. Could you clear that up in your answer please so I can check it?

Comment: @YannBergonzat yes that's correct - typically when you work with canvas, you'll want to set the width and height to define the resolution/dimensions of the canvas. The styling just sets the dimensions of the canvas in terms of the box-model, which bear no meaning when calling functions like drawImage()